# While deploying the application to Wildfly 8, I get a NoClassDefFoundError, but it successfully starts, works and uses the given class

Tags: java, classpath, classloader, noclassdeffounderror

As we know, NoClassDefFoundError means that at the time of compilation the class was available, but the first time it was accessed and tried to be loaded by the ClassLoader in the JVM, it was not found. However, at the time of compilation, my class was in a different package (not in the /dictionary, but in the /model) and as if the class loader is looking for it a little bit in the wrong place.

What is important, at the same level of the package with this class there is a package with the same name (the only difference is in the first small letter) and the error is just about that. However, it would be a strange "name conflict" and I checked such a scenario by creating a package for another class in its package with the name of this class - which, as expected, I did not receive a NoClassDefFoundError on it.
[package hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrJoJ.png)

I think this is due to some kind of classpath settings in the Wildfly itself or some other configuration, but I can't figure it out. Thank you in advance for your cooperation!

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: model/dictionary (wrong name: model/Dictionary)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(ClassLoader.java) [rt.jar:1.8.0_231]
at java.lang.ClassLoader._jr$defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756) [rt.jar:1.8.0_231]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:42016) [rt.jar:1.8.0_231]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:361) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:482) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
```

Comment: It appears that you have a module referencing this class. Are you using custom modules?

Comment: only postgres as data source

Comment: Well, your package hierarchy do not have model.Dictionary class, but you have something pointing to this class. Can you clear standalone/data standalone/deployments and standalone/tmp (this is for wildfly 21, think that is the same for wildfly 8)? Can you grep in your wildfly instance for "dictionary" and "Dictionary"?

Comment: Failed to define class model.dictionary in Module "deployment.e-hospital-1.0.0.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link model/dictionary (Module "deployment.e-hospital-1.0.0.war:main" from Service Module Loader)

Comment: The most interesting thing is, if you rename the package 'dictionary' (in which the ClassLoader is trying to see a class that is not there) with at least one letter difference, then the error disappears!

Comment: Right. Then, maybe, there is some type of unknown internal reference for model.dictionary, as it appears to be a module as starting point. I will suggest that you use a recommended package name (com.example.*)